# How to throw an exception in Erlang?

Tags: exception, erlang

I'm new to Erlang and I found how to handle exceptions in a Users Guide, but not how to throw them. Is it possible to define and then throw my own exception?

Comment: u mean like this [raising erlang exceptions](http://abel-perez.com/raising-erlang-exceptions) ?

Comment: you can post your ans also, the way you have used for other to refer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from [raising Erlang exceptions](http://abel-perez.com/raising-erlang-exceptions).

Example of raising an Erlang exception with `exit(Why)`.

```
-module(exceptions).

-export([sample_error/0]).

sample_error() -> throw(“some bad happened”).
```

> Now lets compile our exceptions module, invoke the sample_error() function and observe >the output of the raised exception.

```
erlc –o ebin src/exceptions.erl
erl –pa ebin

1> exceptions:sample_error().
** exception throw: "some bad happened"
  in function  exceptions:sample_error/0
```

Comment: I believe, this is not an _exact_ quote from "raising erlang exceptions" ;-)

Comment: This answer is **wrong**, even apart from the texts. `throw/1` does **NOT** generate an exception, it does a non-local return. The error generated is that there is nothing to catch the value which has been thrown. Use `exit/1` or `error/1` to generate exceptions.

Comment: @rvirding, in the terminology of today's Erlang, throws are just another kind of exception. (After all, it's the same mechanism as for exit and error.) Calling it a nonlocal return is more a question of how you're using the exception in your program.

Comment: @RichardC yes that might be so in today's terminology, but they don't behave as exceptions. For example a real exception is not generated by throws unless they are not caught. I think which one of `throw`, `exit` or `error` you use should clearly indicate intent.

Comment: Well, what is a "real exception"? A throw is still an exception (showing the intent that it should be caught by user code); it just transforms into a different kind of exception (error) if it isn't caught. My definition of exception would be "something that is propagated by the exception mechanism as opposed to being a normal return value", and all of error/exit/throw fit this description. They all do behave mostly the same, they are just different classes of exceptions.